# IndexError: Index out of range Python Error

Tags: python, sql, exception

My Code:

def email_address_grab(email_list):

```
""" This function takes in a list of emails and puts them into a sql database """


#import module
import sqlite3 as sql


#Setup sql
#create connection for sql
connection = sql.connect("emailList.db")

#create cursor
crsr = connection.cursor()

 #create sql table
cmd = """CREATE TABLE emails (
email_handle TEXT,
email_domain VARCHAR(20));"""
crsr.execute(cmd)


#iterate through email list
index = 0
for email in email_list:
    #split email with a delimiter of "@"
    email_list[index] = email.split('@')
    index += 1

#while loop to put all data into table
ct = 0
index = 0
while ct <= (len(email_list) - 1):
    for i in email_list:
        for j in email_list:
            email_address_1 = email_list[index]
            email_address_2 = email_list[index + 1]
            cmd = f"""INSERT INTO emails (email_handle, email_domain)
            VALUES ({email_address_1}, {email_address_2});"""
            crsr.execite(cmd)
            index += 1
    ct += 1


#get the contents of the table
crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM emails;")

#store contents in a variable
email_address_list = crsr.fetchall()

#save changes to sql table
connection.commit()

#close connection
connection.close()


#return print statement for data
return print(email_address_list)
```

I am getting an IndexError:

File "c:/Users/USER/Desktop/email grabber.py", line 82, in 
email_address_grab(["testemail123@gmail.com"])

File "c:/Users/USER/Desktop/email grabber.py", line 57, in email_address_grab
email_address_2 = email_list[index + 1]

IndexError: list index out of range

How can I fix this?

Comment: you're iterating over all of the elements several times while not resetting `index` to zero, so when `index = len(email_list)` you get an index error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 loops that iterate on email_list. However you only use your variable `index` in your code and you increment it every time.

So let say you have 10 emails in your list. Your double loop will make your code execute 100 times, and the value of `index` will continue to grow. After the 11 time your loop is executed, you will try to fetch the 11th value of your `email_list` which will produce your error, because you only have 10 value in your list.

What you probably want to do is to use your `i, j` variables like this if you want to create every pair possible

```
email_address_1 = email_list[i]
email_address_2 = email_list[j]
```